# What do here understudy, substance and entertainers mean in this passage?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Even though the prime **entertainers** in every one of the three generations remain the equivalent— instructor, **understudy**, and **substance**—the advancement of connections among these three increases from the primary job of **understudy** interaction in constructivism to the **understudy** content interrelationship celebrated in connectivist teaching methods, with their emphasis on relentless systems and client created **substance**.

What do here understudy, substance and entertainers mean?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what any of it means! Where on earth did you find it?

Comment: It is a science article and I am translating it from English. To be honest, I am just going to explode right now because I do not understand at all the sense of this sentence. It seems to me that is machine translation, do not you think so?

Comment: It reads as though it was written by someone who strung a load of fine-sounding words together, to make it seem as if they know what they are talking about. "... the advancement of ... increases ..." makes no sense.

Comment: It is completely meaningless to any fluent English speaker who is not familiar with the jargon (techno-speak) of the writer. I have no idea whatsoever what it's all about!

Comment: If you google that text without quotes there are articles about connectivism and constructivism. Read a few of those. Change "understudy" to "student", "substance" to "content" (meaning, learning material), "entertainers" "generations" , not sure, maybe to  "components", "levels", "parts", words like that.  Instead of  "entertainer", could be "actor", in a more general sense of the word, not as an entertainer.